# Pascal Script Count number of times a string occurs in another string

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to count how many times a String occurs in another String in Pascal Script like shown in the below example.

I've seen the answer to [Delphi: count number of times a string occurs in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265317/delphi-count-number-of-times-a-string-occurs-in-another-string), but there is no `PosEx` function in Pascal Script.

```pascal
MyString := 'Hello World!, Hello World!, Hello World!, Hello World!';
```

If I count the number of times `Hello` or `World` occurs here, the result should be 4.

If I count the number of times `,` (comma) occurs here, the result should be 3.

**UPDATE**

The following function works, but it copies given String again to a new Variable, and deletes parts of Strings, so it works slowly.

```pascal
function OccurrencesOfSubString(S, SubStr: String): Integer;
var
  DSStr: String;
begin
  if Pos(SubStr, S) = 0 then
    Exit
  else
    DSStr := S;
  Repeat
    if Pos(SubStr, S) <> 0 then
    Inc(Result);
    Delete(DSStr, Pos(SubStr, DSStr), Length(Copy(DSStr, Pos(SubStr, DSStr), Length(SubStr))));
  Until Pos(SubStr, DSStr) = 0;
end;
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Have you made any effort at all to do this yourself? You can do it without PosEx; it's been done for decades before PosEx ever existed.

Comment: Yes I done but unable to post my Code because it is not working as I expect.

Comment: Then post your code that isn't working, and *ask a specific question* about that code. Again, this is not a code writing service where you post your requirements and language of choice and someone churns out code for you.

Comment: Okay I will edit my question soon. :-(

Comment: See my answer for comments on your code.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you for the edit. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation is generally correct.

There are some optimizations to be made and useless code to be removed:

- The second test for `if Pos(SubStr, S) <> 0` (within `repeat`) is pointless. It's true always. You are testing `S`, which was tested at the function start already. And the `DSStr` is already tested in the `until`.
- You should save `Pos(SubStr, DSStr)` to a variable not to call it multiple times.
- `Length(Copy(DSStr, Pos(SubStr, DSStr), Length(SubStr)))` is actually the same as `Length(SubStr)`.
- No need to copy the `S` to `DSStr`. You can work directly with the `S`. It's by-value parameter, so you do not modify the variable that you use to call the function.
- Replace the initial `Pos(SubStr, S) = 0` check with the same check in the loop to save one `Pos` call.

Optimized version of your code:

```pascal
function OccurrencesOfSubString(S, SubStr: String): Integer;
var
  P: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  repeat
    P := Pos(SubStr, S);
    if P > 0 then
    begin
      Inc(Result);
      Delete(S, P, Length(SubStr));
    end;
  until P = 0;
end;
```

---

But actually with the Inno Setup [`StringChange` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_stringchange) (which Delphi does not have), you do not have to code any algorithm yourself.

```pascal
function OccurrencesOfSubString(S, SubStr: String): Integer;
begin
  Result := StringChange(S, SubStr, '');
end;
```

*This was inspired by the [@RobertFrank's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5265317/850848#5268784) to [Delphi: count number of times a string occurs in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5265317/850848).*

While the use of the `StringChange` looks inefficient (as it has significant side effects), it's actually faster. Probably because it is implemented in Pascal, not in Pascal Script.

Tested with 3 million calls to:

```pascal
OccurrencesOfSubString('Hello World!, Hello World!, Hello World!, Hello World!', 'Hello')
```

- With `StringChange`: 11 seconds
- My optimized version of your code: 49 seconds
- Your original code: 99 seconds

Though for few calls, all implementations are good enough.

Comment: Thank You! works!, As I hadn't enough time, I became late to Update my question with my function. :-(

Comment: Thank You For Excellent Help! If I work directly with the `S`, aren't the contents of `S` will be lost after calling your optimized version of my function? What did you mean by By-Value?

Comment: If you declare the parameter as `S: string`, it's passed by value (by copy), so any modification to the `S` in the function, is done on a copy of the string and won't affect the variable used to call the function. Note that such function can be calls with a constant string too. - As opposite to a parameter declared as `var S: string` - This is passed by reference. Any modification to the `S` will modify the variable used to call the function - And consequently you cannot use a constant string for the parameter, as the constant cannot be modified.

Comment: See also [Call by value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) and [Call by reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference).