# Extract multiple substring

Tags: string, delphi

I have a string `123HEREWEGOMAMAMIAGOWILLYOULETMEGOMAMAMIATOLOVEYOUSOMAMAMIASOIHATEYOUMAMAMIAHEY` How can i get all available MAMAMIA+ 2 string length ? I need : `MAMAMIAGO`, `MAMAMIASO`, etc.

My problem, on last substring found give me wrong output. It render the begining of string with length of substring given :  `123HEREWE` instead of `MAMAMIAGO`.

I am using [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265317/delphi-count-number-of-times-a-string-occurs-in-another-string):

```
function Occurrences(const Substring, Text: string): Integer;
        var
          offset: Integer;
        begin
          Result := 0;
          offset := PosEx(Substring, Text, 1);

          while offset <> 0 do
          begin
            inc(Result);
            offset := PosEx(Substring, Text, offset + Length(Substring));
             memo1.Lines.Add(Copy(Text, offset, Length(Substring)+2));
          end;
        end;
```

my procedure

```
procedure TFH129.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  s := '123HEREWEGOHEREWEGOMAMAMIAGOWILLYOULETMEGOMAMAMIATOLOVEYOUSOMAMAMIASOIHATEYOUMAMAMIAHEY00';
  i := Occurrences('MAMAMIA', s);
end;
```

Comment: You're adding text to your memo regardless what `PosEx` returns (at the last iteration it returns offset 0 but you add text from that offset).

Comment: You miss the first occurrence, and copy a bogus one right at the end. Solve this by placing the call to PosEx that you make inside the loop, after the line that adds to the memo. I suggest that you consider using the debugger to understand what your program is doing.

Comment: Use a regular expression, instead of looping. Let the regex do it, and iterate through the matches.

Comment: It seems you did not follow my advice from your last question. Debugging is an important skill to learn. See my answer, where the solution already was given in the first question.

Comment: You had a similar question a few days ago. Didn't that answer your previous question?

Comment: @Rudy, I cannot find it. Where is that question, please? (RegEx is an overkill here, I must add to Ken White's idea).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding the matching text in the wrong place, without checking if the added match exceeds the string length.

When entering the `while` loop, first thing to do is to check if the added match does not exceed the search string length. Then you can add the match before starting a new search.

```
procedure ExtractSubStringsPlus2(const SubString, SearchString: string; list: TStringList);
// Extract found sub strings together with the next two characters into a list
// Use StrUtils.PosEx if Delphi version is older than XE3
var
  offset,len: integer;
begin
  list.Clear;
  len := Length(SubString);
  offset := Pos(Substring, SearchString, 1);
  while offset <> 0 do
  begin
    // Test if added length is past length of search string
    if (offset + len + 1 > Length(SearchString))
      then break;
    // Copy found match
    list.Add(Copy(SearchString,offset,len+2));
    // Continue search
    offset := Pos(Substring, SearchString, offset + len);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It took me a while to understand what is really happening with the loop. I now understand. Well done sir, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is as described below in the added comment:

```
function Occurrences(const Substring, Text: string): Integer;
    var
      offset: Integer;
    begin
      Result := 0;
      offset := PosEx(Substring, Text, 1);

      while offset <> 0 do
      begin
        inc(Result);
        offset := PosEx(Substring, Text, offset + Length(Substring));
        // If the string isn't found any more, offset becomes 0, but
        // you still add a new string to the memo...
        memo1.Lines.Add(Copy(Text, offset, Length(Substring)+2));
      end;
    end;
```

Use this instead:

```
FUNCTION Occurrences(CONST SubString,Text : STRING): Cardinal;
  CONST
    HellFreezesOver     = FALSE;

  VAR
    OFS                 : Cardinal;

  BEGIN
    Result:=0; OFS:=0;
    REPEAT
      OFS:=PosEx(SubString,Text,OFS+1);
      // Here I terminate the loop, in case the string isn't found any more.
      IF OFS=0 THEN BREAK;
      INC(Result);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(COPY(Text,OFS,LENGTH(SubString)+2))
    UNTIL HellFreezesOver
  END;
```

Comment: This code is working, thank you for the help. I pick the first answer, mr. LURD was guide me yesterday on my previous question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

One very simple way using TstringList :

```
Var aList: TstringList;
    i: integer;
begin
  aList := TstringList.create;
  try
    aList.lineBreak := 'MAMAMIA';
    aList.text := 'x' + '123HEREWEGOMAMAMIAGOWILLYOULETMEGOMAMAMIATOLOVEYOUSOMAMAMIASOIHATEYOUMAMAMIAHEY';
    For I := 1 to aList.count-1 do
      if length(aList[i]) >=2 then memo1.Lines.Add(aList.lineBreak + Copy(aList[i], 1, 2));  
  finally
    aList.free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Did you test that?

Comment: no, but i think their is no raison it's will not work (maybe need to check if Copy(aList[i], 1, 2) will not make an exception if an empty string, i thnik not

Comment: What if `'MAMAMIA'` is at the end of the text?

Comment: Then try with `'x' + '123HEREWEGOMAMAMIAGOWILLYOULETMEGOMAMAMIATOLOVEYOUSOMAMAMIASOIHATEYOUMAMAMIAHEYMAMAMIAM'`. It will list `'MAMAMIAM'` as result too, but that is wrong.

Comment: why MAMAMIAM is wrong ? it's what he want + 2 chars (here their is only 1 but he didn't say it's MUST have at least 2 chars) ... else add if length(aList[i]) >= 2 then ..

Comment: There should be 2 following chars. MAMAMIAM has only one extra char, and should not qualify. You forgot to check if the string you add has the correct length (`Length('MAMAMIA') + 2`)